# Can't figure out how to create a function which takes two date parameters as a range and checks if the dates between are palindromes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if the title is hard to understand, if anyone has a better title please suggest it or edit it.

I have a project I've been given that I'm having some trouble with.

> Problem statement:  Implement a function named palindrome that
>   takes a start and end date as parameters and returns a distinct set of
>   Dates in chronological order(inclusive of start and end dates) that,
>   when formated as MMddyyyy, are palindromes.

So far I've been able to create a function that takes a single string value, reverses it, then does a check between the two to see if they're palindromes.

**SCRIPT**

```
function palindrome(date1, date2){
    check_date = new Date(date1);
    while(check_date < date2){
        check_date.setTime(check_date.getTime() + 86400000);
        console.log(check_date);

        var reverse_date = check_date.split("").reverse().join("");

        if(check_date == reverse_date){
            console.log(check_date +" is a palindrome.");
        }
        else{
            console.log(check_date +" is not a palindrome.");
        }
    }
}
palindrome(2000, 2015);
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="str_reverse" />
<button id="get_reverse">Get Reverse</button>
```

However, I have no clues as to how I go about getting the dates between two distinct years and then printing them out chronologically if they are palindromes after being formatted.  Can anyone provide guidance?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a JS library that is specialized in date/time manipulations?

Comment: @CyberDude I'm not allowed to use any external libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, something like this?

EDIT: Explanation

To test our implementation, we declare 2 variables. `pastDate` is just some randomly chosen date and `today` is, well, today's date. After that, we call the `palindrome` function to process the dates.

```
var pastDate = new Date('1998-01-01');
var today = new Date(Date.now());
palindrome(pastDate, today);
```

So, the palindrome function takes 2 arguments as stated in the description. The key part is `for` loop itself. Notice how it iterates through the dates. Day after day (that's the `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)` piece of code - it adds one day in every step to temporary `date` variable). It starts with start date (`date = start`), keeps runing till the end date including (`date <= end`) and adds a day in every step as stated above.

```
function palindrome(start, end){
    var date, str = '';
    for (date = start; date <= end; date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)){
```

here it's easy. We have each date in `date` variable and simply format the date as per requirements (MMddyyyy) and set the result to `str` variable

```
        str = formatDate(date);
```

here we only test if the date is palindrome

```
        if (isPalindrome(str)){
```

..and if it is, we do whatever we need to do. In this case just print the result to some `<div>`

```
            print(date, str);
        }
    }
}
```

Palindrome "checker". This returns boolean value. Should be straightforward.

```
function isPalindrome(str) {
    return (str == str.split('').reverse().join(''));
}
```

This is formatting function. Basically, we have some date and we need to output it to MMddyyyy format. So, we take each part out of the given date (day, month, year) and concatenate it. Notice the `date.getMonth() + 1`. We have to add 1 because [getMonth()](http://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp) function returns number of month from 0, means 0 equals January.

```
function formatDate(date){
    var MM = date.getMonth()+1,
        dd = date.getDate(),
        yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString(),
```

Here, we just have to ensure that month and day numbers will start with 0 if they are less than 10. We want the date to be `01022010` and not `122010`

```
        strMM = (MM < 10 ? '0' + MM : MM).toString(), // padding 0
        strDD = (dd < 10 ? '0' + dd : dd).toString(); // padding 0


    return (strMM+strDD+yyyy);
}
```

Just an example printer..to put the results somewhere..

```
function print(date, str){
    var temp = str + ' (' + date.toLocaleDateString() + ')' + '</br>';
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += temp;
}
```

jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/bm6kwjL0/

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you.  Would it be possible for you to explain everything to me?  Not in the comments of course, but could you send me an email explaining how you did it and why it works the way it does?  If you're not comfortable doing that then I understand.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a Date object with the start date then do a loop where you keep adding 1 day to that while still in the interval.

Pseudo-code (not JS):

```
var d = new Date(startDate);

while (d < endDate) {
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + 86400000); --> this is real javascript
    check if d is palindrome
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'm still lost.  I've updated my question with what I have now.

Comment: How do you receive your start and end dates? `new Date(2005)` will create a date which is `2005` milliseconds past `January 1, 1970`, and I don't think that's your intent above

Comment: It's not my intention.  Right now, I'm just passing in the dates when I call the function.